# svn checkout a single file but with full folder structure

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, svn-checkout

Currently I am checking out a single file from a SVN repository like this:

SVN complete URL :

```
"https://svn_test_url/trunk/Documents/filename.txt"
```

Using the below command :

```
svn co --depth=empty "https://svn_test_url/trunk/Documents/" "local_folder_name" & cd "local_folder_name" & svn up "filename.txt"
```

And finally I get:

```
-local_folder_name
 -.svn
 -filename.txt
```

**Question :** I would like to checkout the complete folder structure till file.

So according to my example I expect the folder structure be like:

```
-local_folder_name
 -.svn
 -trunk
  -Documents
   -filename.txt
```

Any help will be really helpful and appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have to know the folder path to check out the file, just call `mkdir` first:

```
mkdir "local_folder_name\trunk\Documents" &
svn co --depth=empty "https://svn_test_url/trunk/Documents/" "local_folder_name" & 
cd "local_folder_name" & 
svn up "filename.txt"
```

Or if you really want SVN to handle it, use the `--parents` switch on `svn up` and change your checkout root:

```
svn co --depth=empty "https://svn_test_url" "local_folder_name" & 
cd "local_folder_name" & 
svn up --parents "trunk/Documents/filename.txt"
```